# Iterating through directory with flask and jinja

Tags: python-2.7, flask, jinja2

My goal is to iterate through a directory in my static file and show all pictures except one "dynamically". I have the iteration working I just cant get the ninja side of things working to display my pictures.

server.py

```
@app.route('/ninja')
def ninja():
    for filename in os.listdir('static/images'):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg") and filename != "notapril.jpg":
            allninjas = (os.path.join('static/images', filename))
        else:
            continue
    return render_template('ninja.html', color=allninjas)
```

ninja.html:

```
<body>

    {% for item in navigation %}
        <img src="{{ allninjas }}"/>
    {% endfor %}


    {% for filename in listdir %}
    {% if filename %}
        <img src="{{ allninjas }}"/>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}


    <img src="{{ color }}"/>

</body>
```

The bottom tag will show the picture of the last ninja turtle in my directory. I can't get the other ninja for and if loops to work.
Please help I just started ninja this week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things going on here.  Let's start with your Python code.  You need to create a list, as @davidism mentioned, and then pass that list to your template.  Something like this...

```
@app.route('/ninja')
def ninja():
    allninjas = []
    for filename in os.listdir('static/images'):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg") and filename != "notapril.jpg":
            allninjas.append(os.path.join('static/images', filename))
        else:
            continue
    return render_template('ninja.html', color=allninjas)
```

Now, your template has something assigned to its `color` variable, which is a list called `allninjas` in your Python code.  This is also why your loops aren't working, because you have nothing assigned to those variables, only `color`.

What you might want to do is change your call to `render_template` to look like this:

```
return render_template('ninja.html', allninjas=allninjas)
```

And then change your template to look like this:

```
<body>

{% for filename in allninjas %}
    {% if filename %} # not sure you really need this line either
        <img src="{{ filename }}"/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

</body>
```

I removed a lot.  I'm not sure what you're doing with the other parts, but I'll tell you why I took them out.  First, you have two loops that print `img` tags with the source of the image set to `allninjas`, which would only print two of every image, except your loop variable in each case is undefined.  `navigation` and `listdir` are not sent to the template from your Python code, so the template doesn't know what they are, and can't loop over them.

Your code defines `color`, but nothing else, so that is able to show the one image.  I'm not sure what you really intend for all of these other variables to be, so I can't help you with that unless you explain further.

If you were to define all of these variables, your template call would look something like this:

```
return render_template('ninja.html', navigation=navigation, 
                                     listdir=listdir, 
                                     allninjas=allninjas,
                                     color=color)
```

In each case, such as `color=color`, the first part, `color=` is referring to the variable in your template.  You are telling what the template should assign to that variable.  The second part, in this case `color` is the variable from your Python code that you want to send to your template. So:

```
return render_template('templatename.html', template_variable=Python_variable)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Wow I really appricate the explaination. I had tried to create a list earlier but I wasnt .append() ing to the list, so i guess nothing was acutally getting added in there. Like I said, I am new. I am so thankful that you took time to answer my question. It was great.